# Issue using num pad keys for Python turtle graphics onkey function

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am having an issue creating turtle.onkey commands using the numpad 1-9 keys as input.

I looked at the source and documentation, it appears the keys taken as arguments come from tkinker. I found [a list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) of keys from the documentation there as well as [this list](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html) and from what I can gather the argument should be "KP_4" for the number '4' on the numpad, but my code will not take it. I have tried more traditional keys like "Left" for the left arrow and these seem to work fine. I also looked into a document on here about pygame thinking maybe it was similar, but the one they list for the numpad 4 did not work either. (it was K_KP4)

```py
def player_move_left():
    x = player_char.xcor()
    x -= player_max_move
    player_char.setx(x)
turtle.onkey(player_move_left,"K_P4")
```

This should take the x coordinate, and subtract the movement amount then apply that number to the player variable's x-coordinate.

*** Solution provided in the first answer***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My (OS X) system doesn't distinguish between "4" on the main keys and "4" on the keypad, both moved the turtle.  However, it does distinguish between "Return" on the main keys and "KP_Enter" on the keypad so I'll use that in my example code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

player_max_move = 10

def player_move_left():
    x = player_char.xcor() - player_max_move

    player_char.setx(x)

screen = Screen()

player_char = Turtle()

screen.onkey(player_move_left, "KP_Enter")  # vs "Return"
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Experiment with the above to see if you can get insight into your problem (e.g. is there any step you left out?)

Comment: the "KP_Enter" did not work, but the fact that your keyboard does not distinguish between "4" on the main keys and "4" on the keypad made me think, the last time I did a program similar to this was in school and in C++ and I remember the keypad 4 being a bit more difficult to take as input, so I didn't even think to try just regular "4" and it worked! I feel so stupid haha, but thank you very much for taking the time to help me!